# Android Studio Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Just updated to Android Studio beta and having issues with the Gradle plugin update. Here is the error:

[image]

Here is the  build.gradle file:

[image]

And here is the Gradle setup:

[image]

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling, I've tried reimporting the project, I've tried using different versions of Gradle all with no success and the same error.

I was skeptical to update to the Android Studio beta as most of the other updates have broken builds but at IO the Google team promised more stable releases. So far not so much! I would like to get back to developing but I've been dealing with this. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you... clicked the "Fix plugin version" button?

Comment: Yes, it tries to rebuild after I click it and then fails with the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change 'classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'' to 'class 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+''

I think I did this manually and then sync the Gradle files again. Should work.

Comment: Thanks for the easy fix, that did it! Not sure why I didn't think to change that, I guess I thought 11.+ would cover 12 but apparently I was wrong.